# Use d3.js to create an array of all links of a web page (not data-driven)

Tags: d3.js

Given a website with many links. How do I read out all `<a>` elements with d3v5.js and generate an array from it?

If you like: The reversal of data-driven.

Example:

```
#HTML
<body>
  <a href="#1"> … <h1>foo1</h1> … </a>
  <a href="#2"> … <h1>foo2</h1> … </a>
  …
</body>
```

```
#JS
var links = [];
var selection = d3.selectAll("a"). …
…
console.log( links );
```

```
#CONSOLE
[
    { href: "#1", h1: "foo1" },
    { href: "#2", h1: "foo2" },
    …
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`selection.each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_each) can be used to iterate through the d3 selection, and populate the links array.

Demo in the snippet below:

```js
var links = [];
var selection = d3.selectAll("a")

selection.each((d, i, nodes) => {

  let node =  d3.select(nodes[i])
  
  links.push({href: node.attr('href'), h1: node.select('h1').text()})
})

console.log(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1"> … <h1>foo1</h1> … </a>
  <a href="#2"> … <h1>foo2</h1> … </a>
```